# Expected number of rolls until all die faces have appeared?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, dice

Suppose you have a die. On average, how many rolls does it take for all the faces (1 through 6) to have appeared?

Also, what kind of distribution is this?

(I thought of this question when watching rain fall on my driveway; I wondered how long it takes for rain to completely cover the whole driveway.)

Comment: You may get your solution from [here.][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428097/on-average-how-many-friends-would-i-need-to-have-to-have-at-least-one-friends/1428105#1428105

Comment: @YashMalik Thanks!

Comment: The expectation is well-known; the distribution is complicated. Do you want to leave this question open to ask about the distribution, or can I close it as a duplicate of the one Yash linked to? (If you want to leave it open, it would be good to edit it to make clear that the expectation is known and you're specifically interested in the distribution.)

Comment: The supposed original does not cover the distribution. In fact, [Jérémie is explicitly told](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die#comment329066_28906) to post a separate question to ask about the distribution.